# Build Windows Phone 8.0 app with 8.1 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, sdk

If I create a BlankApp, even if in brackets it says that is a Windows Phone not a Windows Phone 8.1, Visual creates a Windows Phone 8.1 app...

[image]

It is possible to build an Windows Phone  8.0 app having the WindowsPhone 8.1 SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build an Windows Phone 8.0 app using the 8.1 SDK, you have to select Blanck App (Windows Phone Silverlight)

[image]

After push OK button, you have to select Windows Phone 8.0 in target Windows Phone OS

[image]